# Adding other tables to already existing database via UserContext

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have an application created from the typical template with regular user identification for logins and such.  It comes with the UserContext pre-built, which I have modified a bit.  I want to add another table to the database (I am using code first migrations).

Here is the model of the new table to be:

```
[Table("Disclosures")]
public class Disclosure
{
    [Key]
    public int DisclosureId { get; set; }
    public string ActivityTitle { get; set; }
    public string ActivityDate { get; set; }
    public bool FinancialRelationship { get; set; }
    public string GrantsResearchSupport { get; set; }
    public string Consultant { get; set; }
    public string StockShareholder { get; set; }
    public string Honoraria { get; set; }
    public string Other { get; set; }
    public string DateSigned { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I have it added to the UserContext (and this is where I am not sure if I am doing this correctly)

```
public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public UserContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles").Property(p=>p.Id).HasColumnName("RoleId");
    }

    public DbSet<Disclosure> Disclosures { get; set; }

    public static UserContext Create()
    {
        return new UserContext();
    }
}
```

This is the table structure after it has been created

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Disclosures] (
    [DisclosureId]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [ActivityTitle]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ActivityDate]          NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [FinancialRelationship] BIT            NOT NULL,
    [GrantsResearchSupport] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Consultant]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [StockShareholder]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Honoraria]             NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Other]                 NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DateSigned]            NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [User_Id]               NVARCHAR (128) NULL
);
```

Notice the "User_Id" field that was added.  That property doesn't get added to the Disclosure model.  If I add a new Disclosure, how can I set that User_Id value?  And also, am I even doing this correctly in the first place?  I just basically want to add more tables to this application without breaking any of the identity stuff that already has been created automatically.

Comment: Normally I would say that that `User_Id` column is EF generating a foreign key automatically due to a mapping between the `Users` table and the `Disclosures` table, but based on the code you've posted I don't see how that's possible because there's nothing that declares that relationship. Are you sure you've posted the complete and correct code?

Comment: I didn't post the foreign key declaration that is in SQL.  However, the code for the Disclore model is complete.  This is where my confusion started, as intellisense wasn't showing User_Id property for Disclosure object.

Comment: It wouldn't show up on the model. Normally you would have a property like `public virtual User User { get; set; }` and that would cause the `User_Id` property to be generated. What would show up in Intellisense would be the navigation property (i.e. `User`) not the generated foreign key value. But neither the model nor the `OnModelCreating` is defining the relationship so I'm baffled how EF is making the connection between those two tables. Try searching your codebase for any occurrence of `Disclosure` and see if it shows up somewhere you didn't expect it.

Comment: The only instance of public virtual is in the User model declaration.  I didn't think it was needed to include this, as my issue was with the Disclosure model (intellisense not seeing any User or User_Id properties).
`public class User : IdentityUser
    {
        public User()
        {
            this.Events = new HashSet<Event>();
            this.Disclosures = new HashSet<Disclosure>();
        }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
       

        public virtual ICollection<Disclosure> Disclosures { get; set; }

    }`

Comment: Please remember that I am not even sure if I am adding Disclosures table in a correct way.  One `User` can have multiple `Disclosures`, and each `Disclosure` can only have one `User` assigned to it.

Comment: I went back and and looked over my code from few days ago, and found that I had manually put in the public virtual property to User, and didn't add it to Disclosure before doing the migration.  Your questioning of the sanity of this situation made me realize that it was my own doing.  So thanks for that.  I added public virtual User to Disclosure model, and now things are looking like they make sense.